# jQuery function to set a value for anything like 4.3, 4.1, 4.2 to 4.5 and anything like 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 to 5.0

Tags: jquery

I want to know if there is any function that can convert my values like...

13.1 to 13.5
13.3 to 13.5
13.5 to 13.5
13.7 to 14.0
13.9 to 14.0

I used round function but does not work on my scenario... Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)**:

```
function roundUp(number) {
    number = Math.ceil(number*2)/2;
    return number;
}

console.log(roundUp(13.1)); // 13.5
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s93zb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of guessing at what you're asking, a little vague of a question, but see if this helps.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

And use it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="numberformat" data-numberformat="0.0"/>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".numberformat").blur(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var numberformat = "" + $(this).data("numberformat");
            $(this).parseNumber({ format: numberformat, locale: "us" });
            $(this).formatNumber({ format: numberformat, locale: "us" });
        });
    });
</script>
```